# Installed Django AllAuth, can't find login or signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I just installed Django AllAuth to my project, but cant find default login or signup page.

1) I logged out from admin panel, but still didn't find it.
2) Added signup.html template, but nothing

Picture of error in localhost/accounts http://prntscr.com/9oyu00

*Here's my code:*

**settings.py**

```
    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'profiles',
    'contact',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'src.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'src.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
        )

# Location of templates
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT = '/'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = LOGIN_URL
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = None

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 3
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = "My subject: "
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "http"

ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = None
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = "email"

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 5
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST = []
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_INPUT_RENDER_VALUE = False
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 6
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from contact import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'profiles.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**signup.html**

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

<p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button class='btn btn-default' type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The source of it all was that I had already defined a base.html file without a 'block content' block. You need the following structure inside the body of your base.html file:

```
<body>
  {% block body %}
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock content %}
  {% endblock body %}
</body>
```

I used this [source](http://www.techstricks.com/django-allauth-tutorial-step-by-step/) to find a suitable example, but it's not very helpful other than that. [This other page](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/95) was a bit better though.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are requesting only the `/accounts/` and if you see closely to your debugger (the screen) there is no URL for this (pattern `^accounts/ ^ ^$`).

Your login & sing up page is located on `/accounts/login/` and `/accounts/singup/`.

About editing default templates I am not able to help you with it (never used the AllAuth package) so hope someone skilled will help you.

Comment: I know that the url of login and register page is /accounts/login & /accounts/signup. My problem is when i go to this url i only see base.html page. Not the default login or signup form.

Comment: I can't help you with that because I have never used the Allauth package. I just saw your debugger and told you what was wrong with it.